# Make Chinese text 20% larger

Tags: html, css

I am writing an HTML document with a mix of English and Chinese text.  Chinese is not my first language so I prefer Chinese text to be a little larger than normal so that I can see the strokes clearly.  I am trying to style the document to achieve this.

The obvious CSS solution:

```
:lang(zh-Hans) {font-size: 1.2em;}
```

has a less obvious problem.  At every nested element (of any kind) the font size is multiplied by a further 20%.  In the following example, each Chinese sentence is larger than the previous one.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      :lang(zh-Hans) {font-size: 1.2em;} 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div lang="zh-Hans">
      我不懂。
      <span>我不懂。</span>
      <span><span>我不懂。</span></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can switch to an absolute size:

```
:lang(zh-Hans) {font-size: 20px;}
```

but this makes all Chinese text the same size so, for example, headers are no longer larger than body text.

There are possible workarounds.  I could restructure my document so that language tags are always applied to the most nested element.  Or I could add lots of CSS rules for all the contexts in which Chinese text might appear.  But this is work I'd like to avoid.

Is it possible to apply a relative font size increase to language-tagged text without the increase compounding on nested elements?

Comment: Does `font-size:1.2rem` (note the "r") do the trick?  More on root em [here](http://css-tricks.com/font-sizing-with-rem/).

Comment: @bishop Thank you, that's just what I needed.  If you post an answer with [this link to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/) I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked, answer posted. And thanks for the :lang() selector hint -- didn't know about that one. Cool.

Comment: umm... is that "Chinese" or "Kanji"...? Just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cascading `em` is a pretty annoying issue that, fortunately, has a simple modern solution: root em (`rem`).

[CSS Tricks has this to say](http://css-tricks.com/font-sizing-with-rem/):

> One of the problems with using "em" as font sizes is that they
>   cascade, so you are forever writing rules that select nested elements
>   to reset them back to 1em; CSS3 now has rem ("root em") to prevent
>   that issue. Just declare a px fallback and you can use it today.

For the gory details, check out the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/).